# Increment int by 1 in sql server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, null

How can I return `1` if the SQL below returns `NULL`?

Something like (pseudo code):

```
if sql return NULL value 
then set value to one 
otherwise returning sql result value.
```

Is there any SQL for defining default value to 1 if SQL result is NULL?

```
SELECT  Max(iCategoryOrder)+1 
FROM    [IVRFlowManager].[dbo].[tblCategory] 
WHERE   iCategoryLevel = 1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use ISNULL operator like:

```
ISNULL(your_field, 1)
```

Try following:

```
Select ISNULL(Max(iCategoryOrder), 0) + 1  
from [IVRFlowManager].[dbo].[tblCategory]  
where iCategoryLevel = 1
```

Comment: thanks for quick response, This is what exactly what I want, Thanks again

Answer (score 5):

**Option 1**

Use [`ISNULL()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325.aspx)

> **Description**
>
> Replaces NULL with the specified replacement value.

```
SELECT    MAX(ISNULL(iCategoryOrder, 0))+1 
FROM      [IVRFlowManager].[dbo].[tblCategory] 
WHERE     iCategoryLevel = 1
```

**Option 2**

Use [`COALESCE()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx)

```
SELECT    MAX(COALESCE(iCategoryOrder, 0))+1 
FROM      [IVRFlowManager].[dbo].[tblCategory] 
WHERE     iCategoryLevel = 1
```

> **Description**
>
> Returns the first nonnull expression among its arguments.

Comment: +1 for mentioning COALESCE(), which is in my opinion the better choice, because it's standard SQL